# how do i add extra column in dataframe after ngram counting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the code i have right now, the csvfile that i use has two columns, one with the text and one with the number of the conversation it belongs to. Now i've managed to get the different ngrams from the text, but i also want to have the number of the conversations linked to the ngram. so if an ngram appears x times i want to see in which conversations it appears in. How can i do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


df = pd.read_csv("F:/textclustering/data/filteredtext1.csv", encoding="iso-8859-1" ,low_memory=False)
document = df['Data']

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(document)
matrix_terms = np.array(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
matrix_freq = np.asarray(X.sum(axis=0)).ravel()
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
freqs = X.sum(axis=0).A1
dictionary = dict(zip(terms, freqs))
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary,index=[0]).T.reindex()
df.to_csv("F:/textclustering/data/terms2.csv", sep=',', na_rep="none")
```

Input CSV

```
text, id
example text is great, 1
this is great, 2
example text is great, 3
```

Desired output (or something close to this)

```
ngram, count, id
example text, 2, [1,3]
text is, 2, [1,3]
is great, 3, [1,2,3]
this is, 1, [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we are going to transform document into csr sparse matrix then convert to coo matrix. COO matrix allows you to get position of rows and columns of sparse element.

```
from itertools import groupby
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

ls = [['example text is great', 1],
      ['this is great', 2], 
      ['example text is great', 3]]
document = [l[0] for l in ls]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(document)
X = X.tocoo()
```

Then you can groupby column (for each bigram you have). There is a little trick here that you have to sort tuple by column first. Then, for each row, you can replace index from row by your bigram. I create the mapping using dictionary name `id2vocab`

```
output = []
id2vocab = dict((v,k) for k,v in vectorizer.vocabulary_.items())
zip_rc = sorted(zip(X.col, X.row), key=lambda x: x[0]) # group by column (vocab)
count = np.ravel(X.sum(axis=0)) # simple sum column for count
for g in groupby(zip_rc, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    index = g[0]
    bigram = id2vocab[index]
    loc = [g_[1] for g_ in g[1]]
    c = count[index]
    output.append([index, bigram, c, loc])
```

Output will look like this

```
[[0, 'example text', 2, [0, 2]],
 [1, 'is great', 3, [0, 1, 2]],
 [2, 'text is', 2, [0, 2]],
 [3, 'this is', 1, [1]]]
```